# C++ difference between stream is false and eof()

Tags: c++

```
string tmp("f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9");
istringstream stin(tmp);
string token;
char ch;
int a,b,c,e;
stin >> token;
while(stin){
    stin >> a >> ch >> b >> ch  >>c;
    cout <<a <<  " "<<b <<" "<<c <<  endl;
}
```

Why the output is 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
But why for changing while(stin) to while(!stin.eof())
the output is

- 1 2 3
  4 5 6 
  7 8 9

So what is the difference between  while(stin) to while(!stin.eof())
Thanks a lot!

Comment: the `operator bool` will return whether an error bit is set, `eof()` will only return if you have reached the end of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you don't check if the read succeeded before printing out the variables. The `eof()` check stops the reading earlier (because it hits the end of the `std::istringstream`) but contains its own subtle bug:

**see:** [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

For example try adding a space to the end of the input: `"f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9 "` and you get the same, *repeated*, output with the `eof()` check.

The ideal solution might be something like this:

```
int main()
{
    istringstream stin("f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9");

    string token;

    char ch;
    int a, b, c;

    stin >> token;
    while(stin >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c) // only loop on successful read
    {
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
    }
}
```